# How to iterate through each key that contains the current rider id?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase to place in textviews but the code I have is only giving me one instance of all the keys in "history".

I want to get the data, if the "rider" is equal to the current rider id.

I have tried different solutions here and on internet but nothing seemed to do what I needed it to do.

Firebase database:

[image: firebase database]

The code I have :

```
let rider = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.displayName

    // getting a reference to the node history
    historyRef = ref.child("history")

    // retrieve history key from firebase ....
    let query = historyRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "rider").queryEqual(toValue: uid)
    query.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        // history auto generated key ............
        _ = snapshot.value as? String
        let key = snapshot.key

        // get values from history and place in outlet
        self.historyRef.child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.exists() {

                var dict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

                self.price = ((dict["ride_price"] as AnyObject) as! Double)
                self.txtPrice1.text = "\(self.price!)" // to make double work in textview
                self.txtPrice1.text = "\( Double(round(100 * self.price!)/100) )" // format .xx
                self.txtPrice2.text = "\( Double(round(100 * self.price!)/100) )"
                self.txtPrice3.text = "\( Double(round(100 * self.price!)/100) )"

                self.distance = ((dict["distance"] as AnyObject) as! Double)
                self.txtDistance.text = "\(self.distance!)"
                self.txtDistance.text = "\( Double(round(100 * self.distance!)/100) )"

                self.location = (dict["location"] as! String)
                self.txtLocation.text = self.location

                self.destination = (dict["destination"] as! String)
                self.txtDestination.text = self.destination

                self.timestamp = (dict["timestamp"] as! String)
                self.txtTimestamp.text = self.timestamp
            }
        })

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting only single `instance` of history in case new data added to history ? and is your requirement is to read all the `instance` of history containing the given `rider` uid ?

Comment: Yes, I am only getting a single instance and my requirement is to read all instances that contain the current rider id, which in this case is rider:"if0yDoRdkUc5TCauWwRNUH4bLia2".  So, if a rider logs in, he/she can see all trips related to them.

Comment: in the code you are just listening to event for `.childadded`, could you please change it to `.value`, it should do the trick, but the second query inside the `observer` query is not needed. You get all the data within the snapshot.

Comment: I changed the query to .value and I commented out the .observeSingleEvent(2nd query) and it is crashing on this line self.price = ((dict["ride_price"] as AnyObject) as! Double) and in the log it says: Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x113c01de0) to 'NSNumber' (0x112c9ce70).

Comment: just comment out the whole internal query code block, (code block with "// get values from history and place in outlet") and above of that print the `key` like print(key). At first i want to ensure that you are getting all the history containing the `rider`.

Comment: do I need some sort of a for loop to iterate through all keys in the 'history' node that focus on the current rider? .... ok I commented out the entire block.  all that exists now is let query = historyRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "rider").queryEqual(toValue: uid)
        query.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            
            // history auto generated key ............
            _ = snapshot.value as? String

Comment: I added print(snapshot.value!) and it prints out exactly what is in the history node on the screenshot I uploaded

Comment: It's printing multiple history objects, right ?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Now you need some sort of collection / List UI to render multiple history object, not only showing it into single `UILabel`, is that correct ?

Comment: yes, I believe so.  I am trying to retrieve certain objects from each key and display in a UITextView

Comment: Instead of using `UITextField`, let me conclude on using showing the data on `UITableView`

Comment: I am trying to put these objects into textfields located on a form I made so the rider can view the details of a particular trip.  They get to this page by selecting a row in a tableview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187375/discussion-between-ratul-sharker-and-lizg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the assistance of @Ratul Sharker, my issue is resolved.  Here is what we had to do -- pass the key from History to HistoryDetails.

**TripHistory**

In my previous screen that contains the tableview that leads to the page in question

```
private var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

// didSelectRowAt indexPath
selectedIndexPath = indexPath
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueShowTripDetail", sender: self)

// add method:
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let key = completedTrips[selectedIndexPath!.row]
    if segue.identifier == "segueShowTripDetail" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! TripDetail
        destination.key = key
    }
}
```

**In TripDetail**

```
public var key: String! // container for the passed-in historyKey

// use passed-in 'key'
self.historyRef.child(self.key).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```